# Is it possible to trigger cloud memorystore by cloud functions or cloud run in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, triggers, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-memorystore

From the [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers), it support storage, pub/sub, firestore, etc. But didn't find if it support [cloud memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore).

If one data has been saved into memorystore, what to run a function, how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Looking at the [list of triggers offered by Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers#events), you can see that there is nothing for Memorystore.  There is also nothing offered for Cloud Run, which does not yet have public support for triggers (except [pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/pubsub-push)).